# JSON file won't load properly

Tags: python, json, discord.py

```
amount = {}
with open('amount.json', 'r') as toload:
    amount = json.load(toload)
```

This is supposed to load my `.json` file, however it does not - I get no errors, my dictionary just does not update. I have checked the `.json` file and my entry is there, however when I check my balance it says I have no account. This is the balance command:

```
@client.command(name='balance',
                aliases=['bal'],
                pass_ctx=True)

async def balance(ctx):
    id = ctx.message.author.id
    if id not in amount:
        await ctx.send('You are not registered. Register with `k!reg`!')
        return
    await ctx.send('You have {} doughnuts'.format(amount[id]))
```

For some reason, it thinks my ID is not in the dictionary. Am I loading the `.json` file wrong? Sorry if this is an obvious question, I can't seem to find why.

Comment: What's in the JSON file?

Comment: `{"368442355382222849": 100}`

My user id, followed by my balance

Comment: Are you sure `ctx.message.author.id` is your user ID?

Comment: It should be, `ctx.message.author.id` gets the user ID of whoever started the command, unless I did something wrong

Comment: @cwallenpoole Just did a test, certain that is my ID

Comment: What is the type of `ctx.message.author.id`? If it's an integer, it won't match with `"368442355382222849"`, because that's a string.

Comment: What does `print(amount)` show?

Comment: @match Printing `amount` shows exactly what is in my `.json` file, my user ID and balance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kevin said, my `id` variable was an integer, whereas in my dictionary it was a string. After making `id` a string, it worked!

Thanks for everyone's helpful comments!